# USB mass storage: device side data changes not visible on PC filesystem

Tags: usb, device, enumeration

usage detail:
USB is being used as mass storage device. The device itself is an intelligent component and can create files at run time.

why using mass storage then?
Since I did not want to develop USB DD for different platforms for transferring data. Existing universal mass storage driver can be used for the communication between PC and device

Issue: 
When my device is plugged in to a PC, it gets discovered as a separate drive and is visible in the file system. 
Now if I create a file on the device side, memory is visible to the PC, it does not reflect on  PC's filesystem. The updated data is only visible once I perform a soft reset of my USB device or plug out and plug in my device, since device enumeration would take place again from the beginning.

Question: 
Why the modified data in the device memory not visible on the PC?
Is there any method in USB low layer, using which I can send command to PC to perform device enumeration again?

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly predictable, the host most likely caches the filesystem structure as it does not expect it to be changed externally.
You may want to try making your media "removable", then inform the host of removal/insertion, but I suspect that may annoy the OS (if the medium is not read only) and also your users. This will probably be slightly less traumatic than the device resetting itself.

Comment: You are correct as far as chache of filesystem structure is concerned. But the entire usb drive caching, I doubt its possible. Consider a mass storage device with 32 gb memory, pc cannot cache the entire memory. There must be certain limit to this caching. My assuption is whatever the page size the system is using, that amount of data is cached and rest is fetched later depending on access.

Comment: Presently I have configured my device to perform soft reset, a method to inform OS of re-enumerating the device, but on some OSs it generates an error prompt which is what I want to avoid. I want to send some sort of signal to the OS, so it can start with enumeration again.

Comment: @Adushyant: What FS are you using? IIRC, it should be fairly possible (and likely) to cache the structure of FAT32 etc. I really think the only method other than a reset is a SCSI media removal, though that could still cause errors (eg. warning to eject media through the OS rather than manually, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. You are correct, I have tried this as well, and got same problem. This is when I decided to post my query. I wanted to be sure that I am not making mistake. Presently I am using fat12 FS, and the device can be connected to different OS flavours. I am now planning to work on a java application or shell script perhaps, through which I can unmount the device so that the error is not prompted by any OS.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by indicating the media as "removable" in the lower SCSI protocol layer. When the device changes the filesystem, it then reports the media status as "removed" for a few seconds.
Windows (and Linux too IMO) checks the media state about once in a second, and will show that the media is removed.

Once you make the media available again, the OS will re-read the filesystem with your changes. You don't want to do that too often, because this will also trigger those annoying Autorun dialogs.

Comment: I have configured my system in similar manner, but on MAC it gives an error prompt. did you try this on MAC? I do not get this prompt on windows and linux, but on MAC I always get it. if it does not prompt on MAC for you then perhaps I must have done something wrong while configuring the SCSI layer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with test unit ready (TUR) command response and the request sense command response. Windows will send test unit ready commands about once a second when the media is idle. When you are done editing a file, mark the following TUR response as failed (0x01), the host will then issue a Request sense command which you should respond with 'unit attention' (0x06). Then make the following test unit command response pass (0x00). This will make windows invalidate the file cache and it will refetch the memory.